# Preventing segue from executing until function runs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a multi-step user registration form, and on the first page I am checking the email address from the text field against the database to see if it exists. I have a function that checks against database and returns a boolean that is working but running after the segue. I want to ensure that this value is checked before the segue is performed.

This is the code that does validation then segues to next screen:

```
@IBAction func nextButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    // Validation
    if (txtUsername.text!.isEmpty) {
        helper.displayMessage(vc: self, userMessage: "You must enter a username.", dismiss: false)
        return
    }
    if (txtEmail.text!.isEmpty) {
        helper.displayMessage(vc: self, userMessage: "You must enter a valid email address.", dismiss: false)
        return
    }

    // This is the function that is running post-segue
    doesEmailExist(email: txtEmail.text!, userCompletionHandler: { doesExist, error in
        if let doesExist = doesExist {
            if (doesExist == true) {
                self.helper.displayMessage(vc: self, userMessage: "This email is already registered.", dismiss: false)
                return
            }
        }
    })

    if (txtPassword.text!.count < 6) {
        helper.displayMessage(vc: self, userMessage: "Password must be at least 6 characters.", dismiss: false)
        return
    }
    if (txtPassword.text! != txtConfirmPassword.text!) {
        helper.displayMessage(vc: self, userMessage: "Passwords must match.", dismiss: false)
        return
    }

    // Set global vars
    users.username = txtUsername.text
    users.email = txtEmail.text
    users.password = txtPassword.text

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToPage2", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

This is the function that checks if email exists:

```
func doesEmailExist(email: String, userCompletionHandler: @escaping (Bool?, Error?) -> Void) {

    print(email)
    let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.mysite1.org/checkIfEmailExists.php")

    var request = URLRequest(url:myURL!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = email

    print(postString)

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil {
            self.helper.displayMessage(vc: self, userMessage: "Could not perform this request, try later")
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        // convert server side response to NSDictionary object
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {

                let msg = parseJSON["status"] as? String

                if (msg == "error") {
                    self.doesEmailExist = true
                    userCompletionHandler(true, nil)
                    print("MSG=error \(self.doesEmailExist)")
                } else {
                    self.doesEmailExist = false
                    userCompletionHandler(false, nil)
                    print("MSG != error \(self.doesEmailExist)")
                }


            } else {
                userCompletionHandler(nil, error)
                self.helper.displayMessage(vc: self, userMessage: "Couldn't do it, parseJSON = json", dismiss: true)
            }
        } catch {
            self.helper.displayMessage(vc: self, userMessage: "Couldn't do it, do stmt", dismiss: true)
            print(error)
        }
    })
    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in callback of your `doesEmailExist` method, check the other steps if email is not existing and callback return false(meaning the user does not exist), then perform segue if other steps are also valid :

```
doesEmailExist(email: txtEmail.text!, userCompletionHandler: { doesExist, error in
    if let doesExist = doesExist {
        if (doesExist == true) {
            self.helper.displayMessage(vc: self, userMessage: "This email is already registered.", dismiss: false)
            return
        } else {
            if (txtPassword.text!.count < 6) {
                self.helper.displayMessage(vc: self, userMessage: "Password must be at least 6 characters.", dismiss: false)
                return
            }
            if (txtPassword.text! != txtConfirmPassword.text!) {
                self.helper.displayMessage(vc: self, userMessage: "Passwords must match.", dismiss: false)
                return
            }

            // Set global vars
            self.users.username = txtUsername.text
            self.users.email = txtEmail.text
            self.users.password = txtPassword.text

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToPage2", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Compiler will warn you to use `self` for variables, edit the code with self, then it should compile and work. You might wanna use `[weak self]` as well to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Cheers, it sort of works but now I get the "sorry this user is registered" error for every email I retry

Comment: It might be related with your backend. Or I'm not sure what do you mean by "every email I retry"

Comment: you are correct, fixed backend now your solution is working. Thanks again!